# Text area placeholder is not showing up while having no space or newline between opening and closing tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My text area place holder is not showing up. **All previous answers I have seen here describe there should be no space or new line between opening and closing tags of text area and my code don't have both.** Is `data-validation-required-message` is creating problem ? How can I solve this.
Here is my code:

```
                         <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *"  id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
```

Comment: You Want To Show The `Please enter a message` in Textarea So You can use the `tooltip` is better option

Comment: Your Code Is Correct. May Be In CSS, some property is defined for textarea placeholder font color. May be for that reason placeholder is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I go and try

```
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *"  id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
```

But it`s work for me !:S

Answer (score 0):

It works, check the snippet:

Demo: https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/

```js
 $(function() {

                prettyPrint();

                $("input,textarea,select").jqBootstrapValidation(
                    {
                        preventSubmit: true,
                        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
                            // Here I do nothing, but you could do something like display 
                            // the error messages to the user, log, etc.
                        },
                        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
                            alert("OK");
                            event.preventDefault();
                        },
                        filter: function() {
                            return $(this).is(":visible");
                        }
                    }
                );

                $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).tab("show");
                });

            });
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/css/prettify_bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/css/bootstrap.css">
        <script src="https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/js/jQuery-1.7.2-min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/js/prettify.js"></script>
        <script src="https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>



<form class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="email">Email address</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
                                <p class="help-block">Email address we can contact you on</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="emailAgain">Email again</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="email" data-validation-matches-match="email" data-validation-matches-message="Must match email address entered above" id="emailAgain" name="emailAgain">
                                <p class="help-block">And again, to check for speeling miskates</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="terms-and-conditions">Legal</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="terms-and-conditions" name="terms-and-conditions" required data-validation-required-message="You must agree to the terms and conditions">
                                    I agree to the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a>
                                </label>
                                <p class="help-block"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Quality Control</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="qualityControl[]" value="fast" data-validation-minchecked-minchecked="2" data-validation-minchecked-message="Choose two" data-validation-maxchecked-maxchecked="2" data-validation-maxchecked-message="You can't have it all ways" >
                                    Fast
                                </label>
                                <label class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="qualityControl[]" value="cheap">
                                    Cheap
                                </label>
                                <label class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="qualityControl[]" value="good">
                                    Good
                                </label>
                                <p class="help-block"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-actions">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Test Validation <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></button><br />
                         
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

### Note

Now if you want to display this message `Please enter a message.`  then you have to validate this using jQuery. Because its `data-validation-required-message` is used to display custom validation message.